swagger schema oneOf not generationg Object and List
I would like to get a result like this:
Employee {
    description: Description of Employee
    id  integer($int32)
    teste {
       oneOf
        - array
        - integer
        - object
    }
}

But I am getting this result:

The object is empty and the List is not appearing
My pom:
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
          <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

My java class:
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;

@Schema(description = "Description of Employee")
public class Employee {

    @Schema(name = "teste", oneOf = { Object.class, Integer.class, List.class } )
    @JsonProperty("teste")
    private Object varDeTeste;

I have tried some many thinks but I didn't succeed so far.
Perhaps someone here have any idea about what I am doing wrong
I tried to configure my project properly.

I think you can change List.class to Object[].class so that you will get what you want.
@Schema(description = "Description of Employee")
public class Employee {
    @Schema(name = "teste", oneOf = { Object.class, Integer.class, Object[].class } )
    @JsonProperty("teste")
    private Object varDeTeste;
}


The schema displays the json array properly here.


yes, I agree with you.
It seems that swagger have some problems to undersand List.class, I had to use Object[].class instead

You may mark my answer correct if you agree, thanks :)
